# Call route yourself in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

How can I call a controller action (route) myself when I have the path and the parameters in variables?

I found this in the documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaFunctionalTest):

```
import play.test.Helpers;
...
Result result = Helpers.routeAndCall(Helpers.fakeRequest(Helpers.GET, "/xx/Kiki"));
```

But the play.test package is not available in production mode. I'm using the latest play 2.1.2.

Comment: Kris, be serious... you didn't even specify Play's version, what did you try... Your question for us is `I have a Car how can I do Something?`

Comment: Thanks, I added more information, tell me if it's not clear yet.

Comment: Why not call it like any other method? e.g. return controllerMethod(param1, param2, ...)

Comment: I have the path as a string and the request parameters in a map, I don't know the controller method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use the WS.url("http://my.local.domain/....") for normal requests and the eclipse jetty httpclient for the comet requests.